# Make the compiler assume const primairy types as classes?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, types

> Can someone suggest a better title for this please?

I have an question but I don't know how to put it in proper English. So I'll ask it by some examples:

Suppose I have a struct named Double:

```
struct Double
{
    // Declarations/Definitions here
}
```

And it is used as the primairy type double. Almost exactly the same except my class has some functions like:

```
void Double::event_serialize(Stream& stream);
String Double::event_representate();
```

So I had to create a wrapper for this type (and others).

Now I have a function like this for example:

```
template<class T> void print(T value)
{
    std::cout << value.event_representate() << std::endl;
}
```

Now I can use it as an combination like:

```
Double x = 3.14;
print(x);
```

But if I want to use it as:

```
print(3.14);
```

The compiler will do something like:

```
const double __invis_value_1 = 3.14;

print(__invis_value_1);
```

Right?

How can I make sure (if it is possible) that the compiler will detect it as an Double instead of the primairy type double?

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: interesting although i'm not aware that you can.  you can cast it though if you have the appropriate operator: print((Double)3.14);

Comment: Make them free functions, that's the proper way to extend data-types that are not your own.

Comment: How would I do that? Thanks for comments.

Comment: @Tim: replace `void Double::event_serialize(Stream& stream);` with `void event_serialize(double d, Stream &stream);`. This is C++, functions don't have to be members of any class.

Comment: Ah thats pretty interesting!
So if I would make the event_serialize function templated for the first parameter, and specialize it for the primairy types, I don't even need those wrappers? Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can supply an overload of `print` that converts `double` to `Double`:

```
void print(double value) {
    print<Double>(Double(value));
}
```

An alternative you might consider would be to use user-defined literals:

```
inline constexpr Double operator"" _D(long double value) {
    return Double(value);
}
```

You could then write:

```
 print(3.14_D);
```

Comment: Use either `print<Double>(value)` or `print(Double(value))`, please. :)

Comment: I figured. But the point is, print is just an example. So there would be plenty other template functions which will call those events of plenty other classes like Double. So it would be pointless to duplicate every function over and over again.

Comment: Your second suggestion is interesting. Is it possible to avoid the '_D'?

Comment: @Tim: Then how would the compiler know what it should do?

Comment: @David Schwartz: That's why I want to make the compiler assume that a litteral parsed as an double, should been parsed as an Double (the wrapper).

Comment: So then you want a `Double` constructor that takes a `double` as a parameter.

Comment: @Tim: In which case, no. The fact that `3.14` is a double literal (i.e. represents a value of type `double`) is part of the C++ language. You can't change it so `3.14` represents a value of type `Double`. You can provide various overloads and conversions, but you can't change what `3.14` is. What David says might be the best approach, if you provide a single-arg constructor to `Double` that takes `double`, that means any double (including literals) can be implicitly converted to `Double` if it's passed to a function like `print` that takes `Double` and has no `double` overload.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for the clear information. But the example function print **must** be an template function. Is there maybe any work around?

Comment: @Tim: sorry, I got that part wrong about `print` specifically taking `Double`. The work-around is what Xeo said in the other comment above: once you define a free function `event_representate(double)`, and have your `print` function template call that instead of needing a member function, then you no longer need the `Double` class at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor of your Double that takes in build in double as parameter and then in your 3.14 example it will be implicitly casted to double. You can even give it a default value.

```
struct Double
{
    // Declarations/Definitions here
    Double(double value = 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Since `print` is a template, no, that won't happen.

Comment: I know that, actually the Double class is complete. But the question is how to make the compiler assume "3.14" is of type Double instead of double, while there is none Double::Double(double value) constructor called.